# Acces class methods from classes out of a list

Tags: java, list, greenfoot

Is it possible to access a getter from a class out of a `List` of classes? See my code:

```
List<Object> words = getWorld().getObjects(Word.class);
for (Object word : words) {
    if (word.getWord() == inputText) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

}
```

When compiling it says: cannot find method getWord().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This depends on whether the `getWorld().getObjects` method can be parameterized to return a `List` of `Word` objects based on the class instance sent to `getObjects`. Can you post some code for the type returned by `getWorld()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, `getObject(Class<T>)` would return a `List<T>`. In that case, you could define `words` as `List<Word>`:

```
List<Word> words = getWorld().getObjects(Word.class);
for (Word word : words) {
    // rest of the code.
```

If this is not possible, you'd have have to cast it:

```
List<Object> words = getWorld().getObjects(Word.class);
for (Object word : words) {
    // Probably a good idea to check word's type before casting
    if (((Word) word).getWord() == inputText) {
```